# Ubuntu 20.04 stuck at [ok] reached target local encrypted volumes

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, 20.04, reboot

I got my Ubuntu 20.04 triple booted with Windows and Kali and it was working all fine until today, when it gave an Ubuntu Software update pop up.

I clicked to update the software, and after that it said it needed a restart. After I restarted, the GRUB screen was shown as usual, but when I selected Ubuntu 20.04, it got stuck at this:

[image: boot screen]

I have tried using `nomodeset`, but it gets stuck at `Started GNOME Display Manager`.

Can anyone help me solve this without a fresh install?

Answer (score 0):

I just had this and the only workaround I could find was to add this to `/etc/default/grub`:

```
GRUB_TERMINAL=console
```

Then run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

and reboot.